# How do I change the color from white to black step by step of a rectangle, when I move my mouse away?

Tags: processing

I have a question. How do I change the color of a rectangle from white to black step by step, when I move my mouse away? I'm kinda new to this.

I've tried a bit:

```java
void setup () {
  size (200,200);

}

void draw () {
  background (0);
  stroke (255);
  line (100,0,100,200);
  line (0,100,200,100);

  // Fill a black color
  noStroke ();
  fill (255);

  // Depending on the mouse location, a different rectangle is displayed.    
  if (mouseX < 100 && mouseY < 100) {
    rect (0,0,100,100);
  } else if (mouseX > 100 && mouseY < 100) {
    rect (100,0,100,100);
  } else if (mouseX < 100 && mouseY > 100) {
    rect (0,100,100,100);
  } else if (mouseX > 100 && mouseY > 100) {
    rect (100,100,100,100);
  }
}
```

I would appreciate that, if anyone could help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `fill(255);` is setting the rectangle color to white.  Use `fill(0);` to set the rectangle to black, or `fill(x);` for any value x between 0 and 255 for shades of grey.

To make a fade, you'll need to draw multiple rectangles (drawing all of them is easiest) on each draw() call. The current box will be in white, where the mouse is.  Others will be fading to black.  So you'll need variables for each box indicating its current color.

Here's my version:

```
int boxColor1;
int boxColor2;
int boxColor3;
int boxColor4;

void setup () {
  size (200,200);
  boxColor1 = boxColor2 = boxColor3 = boxColor4 = 0;
}

void draw () {
  background (0);

  // Fill a black color
  noStroke ();

  // Subtrack 10 from each box color, but don't go below zero
  boxColor1 = max( 0, boxColor1-10 );
  boxColor2 = max( 0, boxColor2-10 );
  boxColor3 = max( 0, boxColor3-10 );
  boxColor4 = max( 0, boxColor4-10 );

  // Depending on the mouse location, a different rectangle is displayed.    
  if (mouseX < 100 && mouseY < 100) {
    boxColor1 = 255;
  } else if (mouseX > 100 && mouseY < 100) {
    boxColor2 = 255;
  } else if (mouseX < 100 && mouseY > 100) {
    boxColor3 = 255;
  } else if (mouseX > 100 && mouseY > 100) {
    boxColor4 = 255;
  }
  fill (boxColor1);
  rect (0,0,100,100);
  fill (boxColor2);
  rect (100,0,100,100);
  fill (boxColor3);
  rect (0,100,100,100);
  fill (boxColor4);
  rect (100,100,100,100);

  // Draw edge lines last, over the top
  stroke (255);
  line (100,0,100,200);
  line (0,100,200,100);  
}
```

If there are a lot of boxes, you should use an array, or some data structure instead of many different variables like `boxColor1`, `boxColor2` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir. Understandable codes. You helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to show a grid of rectangles, and you want a rectangle to turn white and stay white when the mouse exits that rectangle. Is that right?

If so, then you need to keep track of whether each rectangle should be black or white. The simplest approach might be a 2D array of `boolean` values. Each cell in the array will represent a single square in your grid.

Set the corresponding cell in the array to `true` when you want that square to turn white. Then loop over the array and draw each square using the values in the array to determine the color.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't that clearly. I want it to turn from white to black, when the mouse exits that rectangle.